# Tag is not returning in React JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm calling a method in `<ul>` tag which suppose to give me all the `<li>` tags for each genre. But it's not working. When I'm trying to console the data it's logging perfectly but when replace the code with return `<li>` tags it's not working.

Calling the Method:

```
<ul>{renderGenre(props)}</ul>
```

logging the data in console

```
const renderGenre = ({ movieData }) => {
      if (movieData.data) {
        var movie = movieData.data;
        movie.genres.map((Igenre) => {
          console.log(Igenre.name);
        });
      }
    };
```

Return `<li>` tag ( not working)

```
const renderGenre = ({ movieData }) => {
      if (movieData.data) {
        var movie = movieData.data;
        movie.genres.map((Igenre) => {
          return <li>{Igenre.name}</li>;
        });
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to return from `renderGenre` function. Try instead as the following:

```
const renderGenre = ({ movieData }) => {
   if (movieData.data) {
     var movie = movieData.data;

     // please notice here added return
     return movie.genres.map((Igenre) => {
        return <li>{Igenre.name}</li>;
     });
   }

   // also here to have a fallback return option
   return null;
};
```

In this way you return the result of `.map()` function from your function if you have any value in `movieData.data`. Other case the function simply returns `null` which is a proper value for **JSX**.

If you'd like to have a much shorter way of rendering the same function as:

```
const renderGenre = ({ movieData }) => 
   movieData && movieData.data &&
      movieData.data.genres.map(({ name }) => <li>{name}</li>)
```

Usually I try to shorten my render function as I suggested.

Comment: @SandipDhang Awesome, happy to help!

Comment: buddy there is a one more issue right after that I need rating stars and the stars should be equal of the ratings number but it's again doesn't return anything

please help:

const renderStars = (stars) => {
    var e;
    for (e = 1; e <= Math.floor(stars); e++) {
      if (e > 0) {
        return <i class="fas fa-star"></i>;
      }
    }
    return null;
  };